# AngularFire return last sorted record by custom key value

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have a collection of data in Firebase that uses my own custom keys to match what we are expecting from our API when it is completed.  However, I need to get the highest value from a key that we created.

Data:

```
-Results
    +20150514-1
    +20150514-2
    -20150521-1
         Field1: data
         Field2: data
         ...
    +20150521-2
    +20150528-1
    +20150528-2
    +20150528-3
    +20150528-4
    +20150604-1
    +20150604-2
    +20150604-3
```

In this case the key fields under my Results are dates with instances, then full records under each instance (Field1, Field2, ...).  I am getting the data using

```
    var FireBaseData = new Firebase(FIREBASE.URL);
    var Results = FireBaseData.child('Results');
    var LastResult = Results.orderByPriority().limitToLast(1);
    var LastDate = LastResult.$id;
    return LastDate.substr(0, 8);
```

However, I am now trying to get access to the $id, or even a data field in that last record, but I cannot get data.

I have also tried:

```
factory('Result' ...
    var FireBaseData = new Firebase(FIREBASE.URL);
    var Results = FireBaseData.child('Results');
    var LastResult = Results.orderByPriority().limitToLast(1);
    return $firebaseObject(LastDate);
```

and then try to access the Field on the returned item, without success.

```
var myDate = Result.Field2;
```